# PHP load all extension dlls

Tags: php, optimization, iis-6, ini

Would there be a performance hit if I loaded a large number of extensions compared with one or two extensions?

I'm using PHP 5.3.8 on IIS 6/FastCGI and if it makes a difference WinCache for PHP.

Comment: enable them and find out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find that there won't be any noticeable performance hit. On our shared hosting platform we enable pretty much all of the available extensions that ship with PHP. These are virtual servers hosting 800 to 1200 sites with 4GB of RAM and two virtual CPU's.